# How to use new version of a mode instead of the default built version?

Tags: org-mode

I am getting this error `"defconst: Symbol's value as variable is void: org-list-allow-alphabetical"` while starting org2blog. I see the issue is that the builtin org-mode which is installed with emacs is org mode version 7.9.3, while I installed the org2blog mode from mepla and it installed a newer org mode version.

My question is how I can use the newer installed version instead of the inbuild org-mode.

Comment: Did you do a package-initialize before starting org2blog? Packages should appear in-front of built-ins in the load-path.

Comment: yup tried doing that got the same error.

Comment: can you dump your load-path somewhere (pastebin)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/46MjEg5k

Comment: What does (locate-library "org") report?

Comment: The built in org release is getting initialized before the new release. This page explains the autoload behavior http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html

Comment: So for clarity, if something loads `org` *before* ELPA packages have been initialised, it will be the built-in version which gets loaded. If your init file uses an explicit `package-initialize` call, make sure it happens prior to anything which might result (even indirectly) in `org` being loaded. If you have no such `package-initialize` call, I would hazard a guess that something in your init file is loading `org` (by default packages are initialized *after* the init file is processed). If none of this is the issue, *uninstall* the ELPA version and follow instructions in grettke's link.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you can add the following at the end of your init file to ensure that the latest version of `org-mode` is loaded.

```
(mapc #'require '(org-version org))
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, it just makes sure that these libraries get loaded. The issue isn't that they don't get loaded, but that the *wrong* versions get loaded.

Comment: @tarsius, I understand your point. Even if it's not the `right` solution, I had the same issue and the above code did force the org version from `package.el` code to get loaded (when at the end of my init file).